# error: 1045: Access denied for user 'user'@'123.10.123.123' (using password: NO) when trying to connect

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1045

I am trying to get a local snapshot of a database by running this command:

```
mysqldump --single-transaction --quick -u user -ppass -h somehost db_name | mysql -u user -ppass -h localhost db_name
```

Even though this has worked for me in the past, I am now getting this error back:

error: 1045: Access denied for user 'user'@'123.10.123.123' (using password: NO) when trying to connect

I can successfully log in with the username and password above:

```
mysql -u user -ppass -h localhost
```

and I have previously granted privileges to the user for the local database, e.g.

```
grant all on db_name.* to user;
```

I also find it strange that the error message is returning user@my_ip_address instead of user@localhost when I have specified localhost as the host.  I'm also confused as to why it says using password: NO, as I've also provided a password.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the remote host that I was attempting to download from had changed.  Using the correct new hostname solved the problem.